# How to use template instead of compose

Tags: aurelia

I have a TreeView based on Aurelia binding and it works fine.

There is one component called TreeView with the usual view and viewmodel.

I then have another view TreeViewNode.html which the TreeView uses recursively.

```
    <template>
    <div content-id="treeview-root">
        <compose view="./tree-view-node.html"></compose>
        <compose repeat.for="item of root.items"  view="./tree-view-node.html"></compose>
    </div>
</template>
```

This all works. However, I would like to turn the TreeViewNode into a custom element instead of just using `compose` which inherits the parent view-model.

The issue with turning it into a custom element is that it loses the TreeView view-model which contains all the  methods to process events such as drag and drop, and item selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bindables to pass in the parts of the view-model needed by the custom element.

tree-view-node.html:

```
<template bindable="viewModelParts">
    <div click.trigger="viewModelParts.itemSelected()">Click here</div>
</template>
```

consumer.html:

```
<template>
    <require "./tree-view-node.html></require>
    <div content-id="tree view-root">
        <tree-view-node repeat.for="item of root.items" view-model-parts.one-time="theViewModelParts"></tree-view-node>
    </div>
</template>
```